# what is the difference between / and /* in ingress spec/rules/http/paths/path

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have the following ingress resource

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-demo-ing
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: \"false\"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - host: test.my-docker-kubernetes-demo.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: my-demo-service
              servicePort: 3000
```

My app was not getting accessed here `test.my-docker-kubernetes-demo.com` i was getting `too many redirects error`

but when i replaced under path from `path: /* to path: /`, it worked.

But i am not able to find how it fixed the problem, any help in understanding or explaining this would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of `/` and `/*` depends on your [ingress implementation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/), for example there are different ways of selecting a range of paths using the NGINX vs GCE ingress implementations:

- NGINX: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/ingress-path-matching/

> path: /foo/.*

- GCE: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer#step_6_optional_serving_multiple_applications_on_a_load_balancer

> path: /*

You can choose the implementation to use by setting the [kubernetes.io/ingress.class](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/multiple-ingress/) annotation.

In your case, assuming you're using NGINX, `/*` isn't interpreted as a glob pattern so only allows connecting literally to `/*`. Anything else would be sent to the [default backend](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/default-backend/).

Answer (score 1):

You should check [NGINX Ingress Controller - Rewrite](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#rewrite-target).

> Starting in Version 0.22.0, ingress definitions using the annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target`are not backwards compatible with previous versions. In Version 0.22.0 and beyond, any substrings within the request URI that need to be passed to the rewritten path must explicitly be defined in a [capture group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html)
>
> [Captured groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html)  are saved in numbered placeholders, chronologically, in the form  `$1`,  `$2`  ...  `$n`. These placeholders can be used as parameters in the  `rewrite-target`  annotation.

You can check version in a following way:

```
kubectl exec -it <nginx-ingress-controller-pod-name> -n ingress-nginx -- /nginx-ingress-controller --version
```

I think your [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) should look like the following:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-demo-ing
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - host: test.my-docker-kubernetes-demo.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: my-demo-service
              servicePort: 3000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find a short explanation for `spec.rules[].http.paths[].path` in [k8s.io/api/extensions/v1beta1](https://github.com/kubernetes/api/blob/master//extensions/v1beta1/types.go#L682-L691).